# How do I perform an animation every-time a post is liked in my feed in swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift, animation, swift3, uiviewanimation

I have an Instagram Like feed
Feed has many posts. Each post has like button.

Everytime user taps on like 
MyUiView

```
let likeImageView: UIButton = {
            let button = UIButton(type: .custom)
            button.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "like_unselected"), for: .normal)
            let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(loveButtonTapped))
            tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
            button.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

            return button
        }()
```

I am getting and passing the location of user tap through delegate.I get correct needed location using this method.

```
@objc func loveButtonTapped(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer){
        guard var location : CGPoint = sender.view?.superview?.frame.origin else { return }
        var loc = convert(location, to: nil)
        self.delegate?.onloveButtonTapped(loc: loc, for: self)
    }
```

Now on my FeedController (which is UIcollectionViewController)

```
func likeButtonTapped(loc: CGPoint, for cell: PostUi){
            print("like button tapped")
            var touchLocation: CGPoint = loc
            print(touchLocation)
        ...
        ... //like implementation and checks 
        ...

 var i = Int(location.x)
 var j = Int(location.y)

let path = UIBezierPath()

 path.move(to: CGPoint(x:i, y:j))
 //more code for animation
```

}

Now, when I tap on like button from the first post I the animation works but when I scroll down to another post and tap on like button, animation still works but can't be seen because it's happening on the top side. I get changed Coordinates for every like button but the path CGPoint starting is counted from the feed starting point. What should I do make it work correctly?

Answer (score 0):

First thing is I don't get why do you pass the location to FeedController while you can do all the animation in UICollectionViewCell's Class. Is the animation happens with any other UIViews that is not inside the Post Cell (UICollectionViewCell)?

```
@IBAction func likeBtnTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if post != nil {
        putLike(postId: post!.id, userId: user.id, isLiked: post!.liked)
    }
}

// Network Requests
func putLike(postId: Int, userId: Int, isLiked: Bool) {
    let httpService = HTTPService()
    httpService.putLikeRequest(postId: postId, userId: userId, isLiked: isLiked, onSuccess: { (liked, likeText) in
        self.post?.liked            = liked
        self.post?.likesText        = likeText
        if self.post != nil {
            self.likeCountLbl.text  = self.post!.likesText
            self.delegate?.replaceLikedPostInArray(post: self.post!)
            self.likeButtonScaleAnimation(liked: liked)
        }
    }) { (error) in
        print("putLikeRequest error : \(error)")
    }
}

func likeButtonScaleAnimation(liked: Bool) {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4,
                   animations: {
                    self.likeBtn.transform      = liked ? CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.4, y: 1.4)    : CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.6, y: 0.6)
                    self.likeBtn.tintColor      = liked ? UIColor.blue                              : UIColor.darkGray
                   },
                   completion: { _ in
                    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4) {
                        self.likeBtn.transform  = CGAffineTransform.identity
                        }
                  })
}
```